# How to find the efficient sequence for my N number of sequence in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, genetic-algorithm

I am just trying find the right sequence in N number sequence.What I am talking about is Suppose we have 5 Machines and 20 jobs have to do in that machines.We will have the probability of 20! that is 2,432,902,008,176,640,000 possible sequence to do it right .What is best Sequence based on the time of completion.we have to find it.
Unfortunately I am little bit confused that how to get the right and best time efficient sequence.
Me stuck after producing the possibilities of sequence.And I don't Know how to get the right sequence

My try

```
var howManyMachines = 2;
var Sequenxe = [
    {
        jobId:1,
        timeToFinish:5
    },
    {
        jobId:2,
        timeToFinish:4
    },
    {
        jobId:3,
        timeToFinish:4
    }


];
var machines = Array(howManyMachines).fill().map((m, i) => {
    var Mindex = i;
    if(i == 0){
        Mindex = 1
    }else{
        Mindex = i+1
    }
    return {
        id: i,
        value: 0,
        jobs: [],
        name:"M"+Mindex

    } });
function permutations(items) {
    if (items.length == 1) return [items];
    var combos = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var first = items[i], rest = items.slice(0);
        rest.splice(i, 1);
        permutations(rest).forEach(function(combo){
            combo.unshift(first);
            combos.push(combo);
        });
    }
    return combos;
}



const allSequence = permutations(Sequenxe);


console.log(allSequence.length+" Sequence to test")
console.log(machines.length+" Machines Available");



allSequence.forEach(singleSequence => {
    console.log("===>",singleSequence)
   //I don't Know what to do

});
```

Comment: What do you mean by efficient? How do you determine efficiency? I don't really see how this is a genetic algorithm...

Comment: I mean Lowest Time consumption sequence is the best and efficient

Comment: Actually it is the starting point for genetic algoritm

Comment: Not really a starting point, all you're providing is the input. It's like saying I've provided the starting point of a sorting algorithm by providing an array of numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only way to get a perfect solution is to check all the possibilities. 
If you care about performance, this should but this should give you a correct solution in most cases while being reasonably quick ...

Main steps area:

1. Sort jobs by timeToFinish, longest to shortest
2. Add first job to the shortest thread
3. Sort threads by total time of execution, shortest to longest
4. Go to 2 and repeat until no more jobs available

```js
var machines = 2;
var jobs = [{
  jobId: 1,
  timeToFinish: 5
}, {
  jobId: 2,
  timeToFinish: 4
}, {
  jobId: 3,
  timeToFinish: 4
}];

jobs.sort((a, b) => b.timeToFinish - a.timeToFinish);

var threads = new Array(2).fill({
  jobs: [],
  totalTime: 0
});

while (jobs.length > 0) {
  threads = threads.map(t => {
    j = jobs.shift();
    return j ? {
      jobs: t.jobs.concat(j),
      totalTime: t.totalTime + j.timeToFinish
    } : t;
  });
  threads.sort((a, b) => a.totalTime - b.totalTime);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(threads, null, 2))
```

Comment: The thing is I have to try all possible sequence in that machine.But code simple does for one sequence Anyways thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

*Best* according to *time of completion* sounds like [deadline scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earliest_deadline_first_scheduling).

Planning of these large jobs in advance sounds like the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). I'd give [knapsack.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/knapsack-js) a try. Source code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/fatihcode/knapsack/blob/master/lib/knapsack.js).

Answer (score 0):

You might do as follows; It will generate 20 jobs with random time for each and then will evenly distribute them into 5 machines.

```js
function groupTasks(jobs,machineCount){
  var  sum = jobs.reduce((p,c) => p + c.time, 0),
   initial = [...Array(machineCount)].map(sa => (sa = [], sa.sum = 0, sa));
   console.log("total number of jobs:",jobs.length,"\n");
   console.log("total job time:", sum,"\n");
   console.log("number of machines:", machineCount,"\n");
   console.log("target total job time per machine:", sum/machineCount,"\n");
  return jobs.sort((a,b) => b.time-a.time)
             .reduce((machines,job) => { var machine = machines.reduce((p,c) => p.sum < c.sum ? p : c);
                                         machine.push(job);
                                         machine.sum += job.time;
                                         return machines;
                                       },initial);
}

var jobs = [...Array(20)].map((_,i) => ({id:i, time:~~(Math.random()*10)+1})),
  result = groupTasks(jobs,5);
console.log("jobs: \n", JSON.stringify(jobs));
console.log("jobs per machine:","\n",JSON.stringify(result));
```